# Interpreter skips part of code in sys.argv

Tags: python-3.x

I have code in an if statement which checks if an argv was passed in the command line, however I have a part of code which should run if none argument was passed by the user (just the file name). Interpreter instead of running that code, instantly jumps to the code which should run if an argv was typed be the user and prints an IndexError: list index out of range.

```
import sys
if sys.argv[1] == '--list':
    do sth
elif sys.argv[1] == '--remove':
    do sth
else: (Which I thought will be ran with no arguments)
    this part of code is skipped no matter what
```

How to make interpreter to run code in else statement if none argument was typed?

Comment: I don't see a loop in your code. If it helps, you need a `if len(sys.argv) < 2:` statement, but I think you already knew that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to access the element 1 of an array with length 1.

What you should do is to check for the length of the array and only after that try to access it.

```
import sys

if len(sys.argv) == 1:
    # do something when no arguments are given
    pass
else:
    if sys.argv[1] == 'hi':
        print("hi")
```